# How do you add strings to all cells within a specified column range?

Tags: c#, excel, range, office-interop

I'm working with a spreadsheet and essentially i want to add a bit of text to the end of a given range that has been saved earlier. I have searched through the forum and come across various techniques that seems to be given all kinds of results.

I have used the following code:

```
foreach (Excel.Range row in MyGivenRange.Rows)
{
    Excel.Range cell = (Excel.Range)row.Cells[1, 1];
    cell.Value += "Add this text";
}
```

This will add the text to the end of each cell within the range one by one however because there are a good 11k records in my spreadsheet this takes awhile. Is there any shortcuts I can take? I have tried allsorts as copy and pasting values. Could i quickly paste a bit of text in the column next to it then merge to save time?

Just wondering if you guys have any ideas what i could do.. To me searching through each row could be quite inefficient. As before i found a straight copy paste using ranges has saved me time before. Maybe there's a special way of using insert on a given column or range that adjusts every instance straight away?

Answer (score 0):

This is vba, but it should be fairly easy to convert to C#.

I wrote this in response to your question. Using `testit` updates approximately 16000 cells, and took about 6 seconds. The basic idea is to copy the Excel formulas into an array, update the array, and then paste the array back into Excel as the formulas.

```
Sub testit()
appendTextToRange "A1:D4000", "hey there"
End Sub

Sub appendTextToRange(rngAddress As String, append As String)
Dim arr() As Variant, c As Variant
arr = Range(rngAddress).Formula
For x = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For y = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        Debug.Print arr(x, y)
        If arr(x, y) = "" Then
            arr(x, y) = append
        ElseIf Left(arr(x, y), 1) = "=" Then
            arr(x, y) = arr(x, y) & " & "" " & append & """"
        Else
            arr(x, y) = arr(x, y) & " " & append
        End If
    Next
Next
Range(rngAddress).Formula = arr
End Sub
```

Warning: If you update any fields that are used for calculation with this, you will break your calculations.

Comment: That looks super i hadnt thought of this approach. I'll keep you updated on how it turns out ofcourse. I was mainly lookin for some sort of quick dump, change then dump method and this probably fills that. Luckily the excel functions between vba and c# are very similar.